# Trouble typesetting pgfplots with context (mkiv)

Tags: pgfplots, context, context-mkiv

I'm trying to typeset the minimal pgfplots example from the Context Wiki but with no
success.

**Context-Wiki Example**

```
\setupcolors[state=start]
\usemodule[tikz]
\usemodule[pgfplots]

\starttext

\starttikzpicture
        \startaxis[     xmin=0,xmax=300,
                        title=http://cryogenics.nist.gov/,
                        xlabel=$T$ (K),
                        ylabel=$(L-L_{293})/L_{293}$,
                        legend style={at={(0.95,0.05)},anchor=south east},
                        width=16cm ]
                \addplot[mark=none,color=red] plot file {sapphire.dat};
                \addlegendentry{sapphire}
                \addplot[mark=none,color=green] plot file {Be.dat};
                \addlegendentry{Be}
                \addplot[mark=none,color=blue] plot file {BeCu.dat};
                \addlegendentry{BeCu}
                \addplot[mark=none,color=cyan] plot file {SS304.dat};
                \addlegendentry{SS304}
                \addplot[mark=none,color=magenta] plot file {Al6061-T6.dat};
                \addlegendentry{Al6061-T6}
                \addplot[mark=none,color=orange] plot file {nylon.dat};
                \addlegendentry{nylon}
        \stopaxis
\stoptikzpicture

\stoptext
```

No matter which setup i use: the vanilla TexLive-2011 or the up-to-date standalone context
i get always the same  error:

```
    texmf-modules/tex/generic/pgfplots/numtable/pgfplotstable.coltype.code.tex)
! Missing number, treated as zero.

system          > tex > error on line 1043 in file pgfplottest.tex: Missing number, treated as zero ...


<to be read again> 
                   ^
l.1043 \catcode`\^^
                   I=12
```

The used versions are as followed:

pgfplots-1.5.1

mtx-context     | ConTeXt Process Management 0.52
mtx-context     |
mtx-context     | main context file: /opt/context-minimals/texmf-context/tex/context/base/context.mkiv
mtx-context     | current version: 2012.04.19 23:18

Any Ideas?

Comment: Seems to work with MKII though.

Comment: Tried that too but had only success with context(pdftex) not working with context(xetex).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to be either a bug on the pgf side or in the ConTeXt pgf module. It's a category code issue while reading the following lines of file `pgfplotstable.code.tex`.

```
{
  \catcode`\^^I=12
  \gdef\pgfplotstablesave@impl@TAB{^^I}
}
```

A work around is to fix the catcodes manually:

```
% \usemodule [tikz]
% \usemodule [pgfplots]

\unprotect
  \input t-pgfplots
\protect

\starttext

\starttikzpicture
\startaxis
    [xmin=0,xmax=300,
    title=http://cryogenics.nist.gov/,
    xlabel=$T$ (K),
    ylabel=$(L-L_{293})/L_{293}$,
    legend style={at={(0.95,0.05)},anchor=south east},
    width=16cm]
    \addplot[mark=none,color=red] plot file {sapphire.dat};
    \addlegendentry{sapphire}
    \addplot[mark=none,color=green] plot file {Be.dat};
    \addlegendentry{Be}
    \addplot[mark=none,color=blue] plot file {BeCu.dat};
    \addlegendentry{BeCu}
    \addplot[mark=none,color=cyan] plot file {SS304.dat};
    \addlegendentry{SS304}
    \addplot[mark=none,color=magenta] plot file {Al6061-T6.dat};
    \addlegendentry{Al6061-T6}
    \addplot[mark=none,color=orange] plot file {nylon.dat};
    \addlegendentry{nylon}
\stopaxis
\stoptikzpicture

\stoptext
```

This example works here with 2012.04.19 23:18 and luatex (MkIV).

**Note:** The catcode issue is fixed now and the workaround is not necessary any more (unless your pgfplots in older than 2012-05-12). The module can be loaded as usual:

```
\usemodule [pgfplots]
```

Comment: This fixes the problem of typesetting but have you took a look at your output? Do you see any curves or the legend? I only see the frame with axis labels no curves nor the legend.

Comment: @Zonk That would be because the data files are not available (check the log file, you'll see messages about this). Replace all the `\addplot` lines with e.g. `\addplot {x};` (and perhaps change the `xmax` value) to see something happening.

Comment: @Torbjørn T.  Aaaah my bad, thanks now it works.